# Domino Server Log - JVM Error

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

```
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM: <af type="tenured" id="5237" timestamp="Oct 23 08:15:57 2013" intervalms="30196.650">
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   <minimum requested_bytes="64" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   <time exclusiveaccessms="0.034" meanexclusiveaccessms="0.034" threads="0" lastthreadtid="0x000000001F498C00" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   <refs soft="1768" weak="6962" phantom="32" dynamicSoftReferenceThreshold="17" maxSoftReferenceThreshold="32" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   <tenured freebytes="2990752" totalbytes="106818560" percent="2" >
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:     <soa freebytes="0" totalbytes="100410368" percent="0" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:     <loa freebytes="2990752" totalbytes="6408192" percent="46" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   </tenured>
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   <pending-finalizers finalizable="115" reference="210" classloader="0" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   <gc type="global" id="5237" totalid="5237" intervalms="30196.694">
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:     <finalization objectsqueued="115" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:     <timesms mark="22.268" sweep="0.616" compact="0.000" total="29.173" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:     <tenured freebytes="58038664" totalbytes="106818560" percent="54" >
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:       <soa freebytes="55047912" totalbytes="100410368" percent="54" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:       <loa freebytes="2990752" totalbytes="6408192" percent="46" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:     </tenured>
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   </gc>
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   <tenured freebytes="58037896" totalbytes="106818560" percent="54" >
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:     <soa freebytes="55047144" totalbytes="100410368" percent="54" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:     <loa freebytes="2990752" totalbytes="6408192" percent="46" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   </tenured>
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   <refs soft="1333" weak="798" phantom="32" dynamicSoftReferenceThreshold="17" maxSoftReferenceThreshold="32" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   <pending-finalizers finalizable="115" reference="210" classloader="0" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM:   <time totalms="29.251" />
10/23/2013 08:15:58 AM  HTTP JVM: </af>
```

In Domino server log, the above message are keep printing, what could be the reason and how can I restrict this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a verbose garbage collection logging report.

Maybe, your server has following setting in notes.ini

**JavaVerboseGC=1**

This variable enables (=1) or disables (=0) the verbose setting of the Garbage Collector (GC) mechanism in JVM,
which causes the JVM to issue many messages about memory usage as GC runs.
JavaVerboseGC=1 enables this setting, which can help you troubleshoot problems.